# GetCompatibleComponent returning a Vector Error

Tags: c++, components, sfml

I'm creating a Basic Button event for a University Project and I'm having problems trying to access an Entity's child.

I am using a Component model in order to create and display all objects on the screen and one "button" is comprised of 3 separate components, a TextComponent that displays what the button does i.e. "Start Game", a SpriteComponent that creates and displays an image above the text, and a ShapeComponent that acts as a "Bounding Box" for my button. This component functions purely as a sort of Event Handler, checking to see if the mouse is inside the shape's bounding box and if so, allows the user to interact with it (like display a message).

Below is the code for one of my buttons.

```
static shared_ptr<Entity> btnStartGame;

void MainMenuScene::Load() {


    //START GAME BUTTON

    auto txtNewGame = makeEntity();
    auto t = txtNewGame->addComponent<TextComponent>("New Game");
    t->getText().setOrigin(t->getText().getGlobalBounds().width / 2, t->getText().getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
    txtNewGame->setPosition(Vector2f(280.f, 500.f));


    auto sword = makeEntity();
    auto s = sword->addComponent<SpriteComponent>();
    s->Sprite("Sword.png", IntRect(0, 0, 60, 60));
    sword->setPosition(Vector2f(370.f, 540.f));


    auto btnStartGame = makeEntity();
    auto b = btnStartGame->addComponent<ShapeComponent>();
    b->setShape<sf::RectangleShape>(Vector2f(200.f, 105.f));
    b->getShape().setFillColor(Color(224, 190, 20));  //just so I can see where it is
    b->getShape().setOrigin(b->getShape().getGlobalBounds().width / 2, b->getShape().getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
    btnStartGame->setPosition(Vector2f(Engine::GetWindow().getSize().x / 4 - 40.f, 525.f));
}
```

Once the Bounding box is created, I do a validation check in the Update function in order to see if the mouse is currently inside the ShapeComponent's bounding box. I get the component of the btnStartGame Entity and get it's GlobalBounds, after this is done, I check to see if the mouse is currently inside the box However this line causes an error.

```
if (btnStartGame->get_components<ShapeComponent>()[0]->getShape().getGlobalBounds().contains(Engine::GetWindow().mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition())))
    {
        cout << "level 1 selected" << endl;
    }
```

I get a Read Access Violation Error at this line in Vector

```
pointer _Unchecked_begin() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return pointer for beginning of mutable sequence
    return (this->_Myfirst());
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I thought at first it was a pointer error but that didn't seem to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

I had created a shared_ptr and instead of referencing the Entity I had created, I was trying to point to a new one inside the Load() function.

Removing the Auto from btnStartGame solved the issue

```
btnStartGame = makeEntity();
```